# R Error in charToDate(x) while using DBEST

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time-series with monthly mean values. The time-series was built up like the following code:

`date00_18.ndvi <-seq(as.Date("2000-03-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by="month")`

`date00_18.ndvi <- format(date00_18.ndvi,"%Y-%m",tz ="GMT")`

When I use the DBEST function from the package "DBEST", I receive the following error:

`Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

The time-series,of class ´ts´ looks like this:

```
     Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
2000                     0.5586051 0.5836955 0.8669510 0.8822613 0.8454232 0.8498964 0.8172346 0.6575267 0.6305013 0.5900626
2001 0.6315357 0.5830158 0.5711033 0.5914131 0.7910069 0.8791512 0.8713150 0.8628057 0.8057766 0.7530995 0.6871537 0.6925474
2002 0.5886510 0.5953657 0.5659760 0.5805979 0.8510186 0.8759845 0.8748747 0.8827877 0.8648766 0.7189505 0.6764806 0.6334654
```

The values of the time-series are monthly mean NDVI-values calculated out of MODIS rasterstacks.

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)

Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Is there anything wrong with the command: "format()"?

Thanks for helping out

Comment: The 'format' function converts the `Date` sequence to a `character` sequence, thus removing the meaning of the components of the character. In other words, DBEST does not know whether '2000-03-01' means the 1st of March, or the 3rd of January. I think if you omit your second (`format()`) line, it might work.

Comment: Dear @Basibo1, I tried out your approach but it still does not work. I also gave it a try with ´´´%Y-%m´´´ so there should be no doubt for DBEST what is day and month, but this does not work neither.

Comment: Could you provide more details? What is the time series you are trying to apply DBEST to?

Answer (score 0):

The way I builded the time-series was the problem. Just check the example in the package and you´ll see.